# Pi to English translator

Tags: go

I am trying to convert pi to letters. For instance, 3141519265 would be cadaeaibfe. C is the third letter of the alphabet. So we would get three. I have created a map with all the translations, but I have no clue how to translate. I'm guessing I have to create a for loop to parse through the pi. How could I do this?

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

var (
     m map[int]string;
     pi int = 3141519265
)

func main() {
    m = make(map[int]string)
    m[1] = "a"
    m[2] = "b"
    m[3] = "c"
    m[4] = "d"
    m[5] = "e"
    m[6] = "f"
    m[7] = "g"
    m[8] = "h"
    m[9] = "i"
    m[10] = "j"
    m[11] = "k"
    m[12] = "l"
    m[13] = "m"
    m[14] = "n"
    m[15] = "o"
    m[16] = "p"
    m[17] = "q"
    m[18] = "r"
    m[19] = "s"
    m[20] = "t"
    m[21] = "u"
    m[22] = "v"
    m[23] = "w"
    m[24] = "x"
    m[25] = "y"
    m[26] = "z"
}
```

Comment: You need to break this number into digits. You can either do this by converting it to a string and get that string's characters. Or use something like `last_digit := pi % 10; pi /= 10`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to flesh out your algorithm a little to determine how many digits you want to represent a character (is 314 "CAD" or "CN" ?). To simplify, I assumed that 0-9 are the only unique digits and this is what I came up with.

https://play.golang.org/p/vgo3gSLqUI0

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func intSplit(i int) []int {
    var r []int

    for i != 0 {
        r = append(r, i%10)
        i = i / 10
    }
    return r
}

func intSliceToString(is []int) string {
    var s string

    for i := range is {
        uv := is[len(is)-1-i] + 64 // 64 is the unicode offset & the -1-i essentially reverse the loop
        s = s + fmt.Sprintf("%c", uv)
    }

    return s
}

func deCypher(i int) string {
    list := intSplit(i)
    return intSliceToString(list)

}
func main() {

    dc := deCypher(54321)
    fmt.Println(dc)

}
```